# Having problems with firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm having problems installing Firebase in a `Flutter` app.

So I tried create a login page using Firebase and followed the example onthe Firebase website where it says that you need to add this code

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'

  // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  ...
}
```

to the build.gradle file, but when I do this and try to run my `Flutter` app through Android Studio, it stops in the "Gradle task assembleDebug" part and prints out in the terminal:
"Build failed with an exception" and "only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove that plugins and change it with this

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
```

Comment: let me know how it went

Comment: sorry for not answering, thanks a lot, it worked